# "French leave" in French

Tags: expressions, traduction

How to translate "French leave" into French?

I have searched for the translation on wordreference.com and Google separately but they both showed different results.

According to wordreference.com “French leave” translates to “filer à l'anglaise“, but if I consider the meaning of "leave" alone in French, it says **congé**. I am confused.

Comment: "To leave" and "to take a leave" has different translations in French. The correct one here is *filer à l'anglaise*. And generally, you shouldn't rely on Google Translate for idiomatic expressions.

Answer (score 10):

The expression is indeed **filer à l'anglaise** (backed up by [Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/filer_%C3%A0_l%E2%80%99anglaise)).

I don't think there's a specific noun for this. If I were translating something like "Where did he go?" — "He took French leave" I would just treat the whole thing as a verb and conjugate it : « Où est-il allé ? » — « Il a filé à l'anglaise. »

In general, a dictionary with a dedicated entry for an idiom should be trusted over Google Translate, in my experience. You really don't know what mélange of contexts the latter has found equivalents in, or if it even knows it should take the two words as a whole.

Also, don't worry about "leave" = *congé* on its own. Since "French leave" is an idiom, there's no way to guess the meaning from the parts alone. *congé* + *français* won't add up to "French leave" and it doesn't have to.

Comment: "leave" may also mean *permission* (pour un militaire)

Answer (score 5):

First of all, *French leave* is not used so often nowadays according to https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/french-leave

More information may be found [here](https://writingexplained.org/idiom-dictionary/french-leave).

In any case according to https://www.linguee.com/english-french/search?source=auto&query=french+leave

a one to one translation might be

> filer à la française

But a googling reveals that French people use

> filer à l'anglaise

instead. I think it has to do with the traditional (at least in the past) Franco-British rivalry.

> Si en français, prendre la fuite se dit "filer à l'anglaise", en
> anglais, on utilise la réciproque en disant "to take french leave".

http://www.dixvinsblog.com/article-les-belles-expressions-de-la-langue-fran-aise-filer-a-l-anglaise-119527538.html

Answer (score 0):

Once it's an idiom, no need to translate it word by word. Endeed, it's (filer à l'anglaise).

Thank you.

Comment: Avoid posting answers to old questions that already have well received answers unless you have something substantial and new to add.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://french.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://french.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/21756)