# Hidden meaning and phrases in "Un clair de lune à Maubeuge"

Tags: vocabulaire, histoire, paroles-de-chanson, jeux-de-mots

I am trying to understand as much as I can of this (historically) well known French song from 1961. (I do not speak French).

I would greatly appreciate any pointers on the meaning of phrases, words, and especially word play in this wonderful semi nonsense song.

Thanks, Joseph

```
Un clair de lune à Maubeuge

Je suis allé aux fraises.
Je suis revenu de Pontoise.
J'ai filé à l'anglaise
Avec une Tonkinoise.

Si j'ai roulé ma bosse,
Je connais l'univers.
J'ai même roulé carrosse
Et j'ai roulé les R.
Et je dis non, non, non, non, non
Oui je dis non, non, non, non, non, non, non, non, non

Tout ça n'vaut pas
Un clair de lune a Maubeuge
Tout ça n'vaut pas
Le doux soleil de Tourcoing (Coin-coin ! oh je vous en prie)
Tout ça n'vaut pas
Une croisière sur la Meuse
Tout ça n'vaut pas des vacances au Kremlin-Bicêtre

J'ai fait toutes les bêtises qu'on peut imaginer
J'en ai fait à ma guise et aussi à Cambrai
Je connais toutes les Mers, la Mer Rouge, la Mer Noire,
La Mer-diterranée, la Mer de Charles Trenet
Et je dis non, non, non, non, non
Oui je dis non, non, non, non, non, non, non, non, non
```

Answer (score 4):

[**Je suis allé aux fraises**](https://www.expressio.fr/expressions/aller-aux-fraises)  (I found a remote place to get laid)
**Je suis revenu de Pontoise**.
[**J'ai filé à l'anglaise**](https://www.expressio.fr/expressions/filer-a-l-anglaise)  (I took the [French leave](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/30257/french-leave-in-french), I quietly left)
**Avec une Tonkinoise**. (Probably a reference to a famous song "[La tonkinoise](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_Petite_Tonkinoise)" and a bawdy song using the same music but different lyrics)

**Si j'ai** [**roulé ma bosse**](https://www.expressio.fr/expressions/rouler-sa-bosse), (If I have been around)
**Je connais l'univers**.
**J'ai même** [**roulé carrosse**](https://www.expressio.fr/expressions/rouler-carrosse) (I have been very rich)
**Et j'ai roulé les R.** (I even thrilled my R's, a last pun on three possible usages of *rouler*)
**Et je dis non, non, non, non, non

Oui je dis non, non, non, non, non, non, non, non, non**  (*Oui je dis non*: kind of oxymoron)

**Tout ça n'vaut pas**  (It doesn't worth)
**Un clair de lune a Maubeuge** (A moonlight in Maubeuge isn't expected to be special, possibly a pun with *lune* that can mean "buttocks")
**Tout ça n'vaut pas**
**Le doux soleil de Tourcoing** (**Coin-coin ! oh je vous en prie**) (Pun on the town name and "quack-quack")
**Tout ça n'vaut pas**
**Une croisière sur la Meuse** (Like the previous references to tourism in the Nord, it is ironical)
**Tout ça n'vaut pas des vacances au Kremlin-Bicêtre**  (a town near Paris but a pun on Moskow's Kremlin)

**J'ai fait toutes les bêtises qu'on peut imaginer** (I did all the silly things you can imagine)
**J'en ai fait à ma guise et aussi à Cambrai** (I did them as I liked but also at Cambrai - A pun on the [bêtises de Cambrai](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%AAtise_de_Cambrai))
**Je connais toutes les Mers, la Mer Rouge, la Mer Noire,**  ( I have visited all the seas, The Red Sea, The Black Sea)
**La Mer-diterranée, la Mer de Charles Trenet** (Pun on Mer **Mé**diterranée, Charles Trenet's *[La mer](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_Mer_(chanson_de_Charles_Trenet))*, a very famous song and mother, a pun on *mer*, sea, and *mère*, mother)
**Et je dis non, non, non, non, non**
**Oui je dis non, non, non, non, non, non, non, non, non**

Comment: About *La Mer de Charles Trenet*: I rather see an allusion to his famous song *La Mer*.

Comment: @Greg Yes, that's right. I think that's both an allusion and a pun.

Comment: For filer à l'anglaise : https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/30257/french-leave-in-french

Comment: Isn't that song simply a love declaration to the North of France?

Comment: @LaurentS. There is certainly more than one level of understanding, but I believe irony is more likely than true love. Especially during the times when these lyrics were written when the Nord was much more industrial (coal mining, steel industry, textile) than touristic.

Comment: Not to mention the anticipated smoky and cloudy sky made Maubeuge the last place to expect enjoying a moonlight or Tourcoing "sweet sunshine".

Answer (score 2):

> ([Wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Un_clair_de_lune_%C3%A0_Maubeuge_(chanson)))
> *Un clair de lune à Maubeuge* est une chanson composée en 1961 par Pierre Perrin, alors chauffeur de taxi à Paris. Elle connaît un grand succès et est reprise par de nombreux interprètes dont Claude François et Annie Cordy, la version la plus célèbre étant celle enregistrée par Bourvil en 1962.
> L'histoire du succès de cette chanson inspire le film homonyme qui sort en 1962, avec Pierre Perrin dans son propre rôle.
> La chanson reste associée à la ville de Maubeuge, où les références au « clair de lune » dans les noms d'établissements et les produits dérivés sont nombreuses

*Facts extracted from the above text*

The song "*Un clair de lune à Maubeuge*" has been composed in 1961 by Pierre Perrin, a taxi driver in Paris; there is then a film made in 1962, inspired from the song, and to which was given the name "Clair de lune à Maubeuge"; Pierre Perrin plays himself in the film, that is, he is a taxi driver in the film; however, in the film he is called Paul Prunier.

> [Le Figaro](https://tvmag.lefigaro.fr/programme-tv/programme/un-clair-de-lune-a-maubeuge-f29215)
> Résumé de Un clair de Lune à Maubeuge
> Paul, chauffeur de taxi à Paris, a deux amours : sa fiancée Virginie et la musique. Sorti du Conservatoire avec un premier prix, il propose, mais en vain, ses oeuvres classiques aux éditeurs. Un jour, lorsqu'il amène des clients aux courses, il parie sur un toquard nommé Maubeuge et gagne. Il fête cette victoire avec ses amis et pour la circonstance, il compose "Tout ça ne vaut pas un clair de lune à Maubeuge". Monique, qui se trouve parmi les fêtards, est secrétaire à la radio. Elle fait graver un disque avec l'enregistrement pris au magnétoscope

> ([Wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Un_clair_de_lune_%C3%A0_Maubeuge))
> Paul Prunier, chauffeur de taxi parisien, a composé une chanson Un clair de lune à Maubeuge qu'une amie, Monique, employée dans une compagnie de radio, a fait graver sur un disque. Le disque passe au début d'une émission classique. Vu le succès, on recherche l'auteur pour lui faire un « pont d'or ». Charly, directeur d'une société de disques, retrouve Paul et signe avec lui. Paul Prunier subit alors toutes les exigences publicitaires engendrées par son succès. Il résiste à la fatigue de sa nouvelle vie, épouse Virginie et part en voyage de noces. Hélas, même au Japon, son Clair de lune à Maubeuge l'a rejoint.
> Le film est inspiré de l'histoire vraie de Pierre Perrin qui écrit et chante la chanson Un clair de lune à Maubeuge en 1962, qui obtient un succès phénoménal et est reprise par de nombreux interprètes en France. Ce sera sa seule apparition comme artiste chanteur.

*More facts extracted from the preceding two sources*

One day, as he drove customers to horse races, he  bet on an outsider called Maubeuge; the horse, nevertheless happened to win. This inspires him with the composition of the song "Tout ça ne vaut pas un clair de lune à Maubeuge".
In the song as the film shows it, at least, the name "Maubeuge" is not unequivocally connected with the city called Maubeuge, but also with a mediocre horse at the races; here again, nonsense rules.

Looking at the song, now, the "not worth a moon-lit night in Maubeuge" (ne vaut pas un clair de lune à Maubeuge) is put on an equal footing with "not worth the sweet sun in Tourcoing" (n'vaut pas Le doux soleil de Tourcoing), then with "not worth a boat ride on the Meuse river" (n'vaut pas Une croisière sur la Meuse), and finally with "not worth a vacation in Kremlin-Bicêtre" (n'vaut pas des vacances au Kremlin-Bicêtre). The plain appearance of it all is that there is nothing special with the places named but that instead the particular pleasures named (moon-lit night, sweet sun, boat ride, vacation) are considered to be something that has more value; that is the only sense that can be made out of all that.

This point of view is confirmed by another source ([Voix du Nord](https://www.lavoixdunord.fr/art/region/maubeuge-de-a-a-z-l-comme-la-lune-et-son-fameux-clair-ia23b44386n1471305))

> Il y a la chanson, mais il y a aussi le film. Et, sur le principe de la poule et de l’œuf, au fil des ans on oublie parfois lequel des deux a placé en premier Maubeuge sur la carte.
> It is not known which, of the 1961 song and the 1962 film, is the first to make Maubeuge famous.

This again shows that there is nothing special in the environment of Maubeuge which should endow the city with  particularly interesting moon-lit nights.